# Ncurses - why doesn't printing a string using mvprintw() when multiple arguments in function call are present not work?

Tags: c, arrays, string, ncurses

I've just started using `ncurses`. An array `validity` defined as

```
static const char* validity[] = {
    "invalid",
    "valid"
};
```

allows me to map the `0` to `invalid` and the `1` to `valid` where necessary in order to make a more readable output in my application.

I also have the following lines in my code:

```
if(data->pos != NULL) {
    mvprintw(4, 0,
             "Position: X %5d    Y %5d    Z %5d    \n",
             data->pos->x, data->pos->y, data->pos->z);
    // ...
}
```

This allows me to output a 3D coordinate that is stored inside a `struct data`, which is updated multiple times every second and filled with new coordinates. It works without any issues.

Next thing I have is use `mvprintw(...)` to output a single string argument:

```
if(data->detected != NULL) {
    mvprintw(5, 0,
             "Detected: %s\n",
             booleans[data->detected]);
}
```

where `booleans` is very similar to the `validity` array but with `true` and `false` strings inside to map boolean values to strings. This works too!

However the following code outputs a strange result:

```
if(data->validity_check != NULL) {
    mvprintw(11, 0,
             "Validity:     %d [%s]\n",
             data->validity_check->timestamp,
             validity[data->validity_check->valid]);
}
```

`validity_check` is just another `struct` that contains a `timestamp` (as long integer) and a `valid` flag which can be either `0` or `1`.

The output should look for example like

```
Validity:    123456789 [invalid]
```

but instead I get

```
Validity:    123456789 [(null)]
```

I was quite surprised by this and made an output using `printf()` to see if `valid` actually contained valid data or not (that's the problem with C-arrays - no check for out of bounds). The result: it did. The values were jumping between `0` and `1` as expected. For some reason however the second argument appeared to be "broken". I even removed the retrieval from the array and used a hard-coded argument value but still no change.

Further investigation made me rewrite this part of the code like this:

```
if(data->validity_check != NULL) {
    mvprintw(11, 0,
             "Validity:     %d",
             data->validity_check->timestamp);
    printw(" [%s]\n", validity[data->validity_check->valid]);
}
```

It worked without any issues and I got the desired result. However I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I have looked the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mvprintw) multiple times but I'm probably missing something since I can't find anything that can explain this behaviour.

Comment: The code snippet I've posted above and the change that I've made for it to work is the only thing I have changed in my entire code (sadly can't post it here).

Comment: "... that contains a timestamp (as long integer) ..." — If it is a `long int`, you should use the `%ld` format. Turn on your warnings and you should be told about such format mismatches.

Comment: what data type is `data->validity_check->valid` and how is it initialised?

Comment: @Stargateur: Okay, convinced. I've written one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

> `validity_check` is just another `struct` that contains a `timestamp` (as long integer) and a `valid` flag which can be either `0` or `1`.

If `timestamp` is a `long int`, you should use the `%ld` format instead of just `%d`:

```
if (data->validity_check != NULL) {
    mvprintw(11, 0,
             "Validity:     %ld [%s]\n",
             data->validity_check->timestamp,
             validity[data->validity_check->valid]);
}
```

The `printf` family of functions are variadicfunctions and the format string must tell them exactly which type to use. (This is diffferent to normal functions, where the type of arguments is known and types get narrows or promoted as appropriate.)

That's a common type of error, but enabling warnings should tell you about such format mismatches, at least in GCC and Clang.

Comment: *facepalm* Yeap, that was the problem.